# Join list with table in linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ef-code-first

I have a problem. I get all data in var type variable and then want to apply a join with database table in code first approach. Facing problem, lot of search on internet and apply but failed.

```
var joinedData = 
    from menuGroup in _menuGroupMenusRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(x => x.GroupId == input.GroupId)
    join menus in _menuRepository.GetAll() 
        on menuGroup.MenuId equals menus.Id
    join categSubcateg in _menuCategSubCategRepository.GetAll() 
        on menus.Id equals categSubcateg.MenuId
    join categ in _menuCategoryRepository.GetAll() 
        on categSubcateg.CategoryId equals categ.Id
    select new
    {
        CategoryId = categSubcateg.CategoryId,
        CategoryName = categ.Category,
    };
```

Now I want `joinedData` variable join with `MainMenuSort` table.
MainMenuSort table also have `groupid` and `categoryid`.

Comment: is that ok or you want something else ??

Comment: I recommend you look into using Navigation properties (if your setup has them) instead of joins https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: i am checking these solutions. will confirm u once done. thanks

Comment: Thank Juharr. I like this article. but previous solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to perform join you just need to do as below

```
 var q=(from jd in joinedData 
         join mms in dataContext.MainMenuSort 
         on jd.CategoryId equals mms.CategoryId 
 select jd).ToList();
```

if its datatable then

```
 var q=(from jd in joinedData 
         join mms in dtMainMenuSort.AsEnumerable() 
         on jd.CategoryId equals mms.Field<int>("CategoryId")
 select jd).ToList();
```